# A word whose meaning is very close to dangerous

Tags: adjectives

I am looking for an adjective to write "Anger is a ____ feeling" instead of "Anger can have dangerous consequences". Could you please help out?

Comment: Is "troublesome" correct choice?

Comment: 'troublesome' might work--it's your meaning, so you'll have to choose what's best. I'll suggest 'perilous'.

Comment: What is the context for this sentence?

Comment: would 'lethal' work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- perilous

> per·il·ous
>   \ˈper-ə-ləs, ˈpe-rə-\
>   adjective
>   : full of danger
>   :full of or involving peril

http://i.word.com/idictionary/perilous

From:

> per·il
>   \ˈper-əl, ˈpe-rəl\
>   noun
>   : the possibility that you will be hurt or killed or that something unpleasant or bad will happen
>   : something that is likely to cause injury, pain, harm, or loss

http://i.word.com/idictionary/peril

Answer (score 0):

*Anger can be a **pernicious** emotion.*

*Anger can be a **deleterious** emotion.*

> pernicious: having a harmful effect, especially in a gradual or subtle way. [OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/pernicious)
>
> deleterious: if something is deleterious, it does harm or makes things
>   worse. Smoking has obvious deleterious effects on your health, not to
>   mention your social life.
>   [vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/deleterious)

Answer (score -1):

**precarious** or **precipitous** might suit.

> **precarious** *adj.* not securely held or in position; dangerously likely to fall or collapse.
>
> **precipitous** *adj.* dangerously high or steep.

Comment: Precipitous is good, but not in the sense you quoted. Try "precipitate(adj):   happening very quickly or too quickly without enough thought or planning"   http://i.word.com/idictionary/precipitate

Answer (score -1):

Based on the sentence you're replacing: **Consequential**

Anger is a /an oftentimes/ **consequential** feeling

**Unpredictable** could also work.

Anger is an **unpredictable** feeling

**Reckless** possibly

Anger is a **reckless** feeling

**Treacherous**

Anger is a **treacherous** feeling

**Unstable**

Anger is an **unstable** feeling

**Jeopardous**

Anger is a jeopardous feeling

> jeopardous
>   adjective
>   1. perilous; dangerous; hazardous; risky.